# Run several string substitutions safely

Tags: text, awk, gawk

I have to run many substitutions on a text file and I need to distinguish a string that has been written in place of something else from the same string if it was originally there.

For instance, say I want to replace `a` with `b`, and `b` with `c` in the second field of the following file (to get `b c c`)

```
a a
a b
b c
```

if I run `awk '$2 == "a" {$2 = "b"}; $2 == "b" {$2 = "c"} 1' file` obviously I get

```
a c
a c
b c
```

I could pay attention to the order in which I run the substitutions here, but not really in the real case. I'd like to have a flexible script where I can write the substitutions in any order and not have to worry about values being overwritten. I've tried with an optimistic `awk '$2 == "a" {$2 = b}; $2 == "b" {$2 = c}; b = "b"; c = "c"; 1' file` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to perform the substitution at most once, you're better off with `if ... else if ...`

```
awk '{
    if      ($2 == "a") {$2 = "b"}
    else if ($2 == "b") {$2 = "c"}
    else if ($2 == "c") {$2 = "a"}
    print
}' <<END
a a
a b
b c
END
```

```
a b
a c
b a
```

Format the code to suit your style.

---

Another approach that may be more elegant:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {repl["a"] = "b"; repl["b"] = "c"; repl["c"] = "a"}
    $2 in repl {$2 = repl[$2]}
    1
' <<END
a a
a b
b c
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The general, idiomatic approach to not changing a string that you just changed is to map the old values to strings that cannot appear in the input and then convert those to the new values:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    old2new["a"] = "b"
    old2new["b"] = "c"
}
{
    # Step 1 - put an "X" after every "@" so "@<anything else>"
    # cannot exist in the input from this point on.
    gsub(/@/,"@X",$2)

    # Step 2 - map "old"s to intermediate strings that cannot exist
    c=0
    for (old in old2new) {
        gsub(old,"@"c++,$2)
    }

    # Step 3 - map the intermediate strings to the new strings
    c=0
    for (old in old2new) {
        gsub("@"c++,old2new[old],$2)
    }

    # Step 4 - restore the "@X"s to "@"s
    gsub(/@X/,"@",$2)

    # Step 5 - print the record
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a b
a c
b c
```

I used `gsub()`s as that's the most common application of this but feel free to use `if`s if that's more appropriate for your case.

Obviously the approach of just adding concatenating `c++` to the end of `@` only works for up to 10 substitutions, you'd have to come up with a mapping to other characters for more than that (which is trivial but just don't trip over RE metacharacters).